# Not able to use socket.io, reference error: io not defined

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Below is my code of server.js, script.js and room.ejs.
Error, the console showing, is-
9cc59f6c-44ef-4555-b9f7-2331159997f8:17 GET http://localhost:3030/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
script.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
at script.js:1

I have tried many things, and not able to find the bug, please help!

```js
const express=require('express');
const app=express();
const server=require('http').Server(app);
const {v4: uuidv4}= require('uuid');
const io=require('socket.io')(server)

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.redirect(`/${uuidv4()}`);
})

app.get('/:room',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('room',{roomId :req.params.room});
})

io.on('connection',socket=>{
    socket.on('join-room',()=>{
        console.log("Room Joined");
    })
})
//now need to import socket.io in script.js

app.listen(3030);
```

```js
const socket=io('/');
const videoGrid=document.getElementById('video-grid');
const myVideo=document.createElement('video');
myVideo.muted=true;

let myVideoStream
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video:true,
    audio:true
}).then(stream=>{
    myVideoStream=stream;
    addVideoStream(myVideo,stream);
})

socket.emit('join-room');

const addVideoStream=(video,stream)=>{
    video.srcObject=stream;
    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata',()=>{
        video.play();
    })
    videoGrid.append(video);
}
```

```css
#video-grid{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
}

video{
    height:300px;
    width:400px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Zoom RJ</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    
    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="video-grid">

    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suspect the path in this script tag is incorrect: `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` and the page never downloads the socket.io client code

Comment: What should be written in place? Please help